# SSIS - How can a power query's output be the import of another power query in a data flow

Tags: ssis, powerquery, dataflowtask

In an SSIS Data Flow I want to include 2 Power Query Sources, in order to pass the output of the 1st one to the input of the 2nd one. I am guessing i need some in-between step to join the 2 PQs, or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an environment set up to test this, but reading through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/power-query-source?view=sql-server-2017)
I think what you're going to do is have the second PQ Source use a query mode of "Single Query from Variable"

That means that however you pull data in the first query, you have to get the data into something you can work with. That might be a custom script component acting as a destination, an ado.net recordset destination, *something*. You'd then need to manipulate the data to build your query and then have a second data flow run.

Comment: Hi billinkc, thank you for the suggestion. It works well and I think it is the safest way to develop it.